Compare the stability of pentan-2-ylium (CH3CH+CH2CH2CH3) and pentan-3-ylium (CH3CH2CH+CH2CH3)
I hesitated because of the inductive effect of 2 ethyl groups + hyperconjugation of 4 alpha hydrogens vs. 1 methyl + 1 propyl groups + hyperconjugation of 5 alpha hydrogens. Can anyone explain this to me? Appreciate your help.

This question is answered here

Indeed, it looks like a duplicate of When 2-pentene reacts with HBr, what will be the major product?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I think from among pentan-2-ylium ($\ce{CH3CH+CH2CH2CH3}$) and pentan-3-ylium ($\ce{CH3CH2CH+CH2CH3}$), pentan-3-ylium would be more stable, here's why:
Hyperconjugation:
Pentan-2-ylium benefits from 5 alpha hydrogens . While in pentan-3-ylium, there are 4 alpha hydrogens (2 from each ethyl group). So, Pentan-2-ylium has a slight edge in hyperconjugation.
Inductive Effect:
In Inductive Effect, Pentan-3-ylium, has a slight edge, as electron density donated by two ethyl groups would be slightly more than electron density donated by one methyl and one propyl groups of Pentan-2-ylium.
Dominant Effect is Inductive Effect.
Hence, pentan-3-ylium can be considered as more stable than pentan-2-ylium.
